# Exchange mapi option not available after Exchange support for the Evolution groupware suite installed

Tags: ms-exchange

My Ubuntu version is 13.04 (Kyrin), 'Evolution' and 'Exchange support for the Evolution groupware suite' are installed. But there wasn't an option for exchange mapi available when I tried to sets my exchange account in 'Evolution'. --- What I mean there is no such selection in the drop-down list!

The sever is 'MS Exchange 2010'. 'OWA' in Ubuntu and 'OUTLOOK 2013/2010' in WINDOWS for this account works correct.

Is there anyone encountered this problem? I have no idea to deal this...

My evolution information as below:

```
ii  evolution                                 3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        groupware suite with mail client and organizer

ii  evolution-common                          3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       all          architecture independent files for Evolution

ii  evolution-data-server                     3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        evolution database backend server

ii  evolution-data-server-common              3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       all          architecture independent files for Evolution Data Server

ii  evolution-mapi                            3.6.2-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Exchange support for the Evolution groupware suite

ii  evolution-plugins                         3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        standard plugins for Evolution
ii  libebackend-1.2-5                         3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Utility library for evolution data servers

ii  libebook-1.2-14                           3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Client library for evolution address books
ii  libecal-1.2-15                            3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Client library for evolution calendars

ii  libedata-book-1.2-15                      3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Backend library for evolution address books

ii  libedata-cal-1.2-18                       3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Backend library for evolution calendars

ii  libedataserver-1.2-17                     3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Utility library for evolution data servers

ii  libedataserverui-3.0-4                    3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        GUI utility library for evolution data servers

ii  libevolution                              3.6.4-0ubuntu1                       amd64        evolution libraries
```

Answer (score 8):

Try installing the package python-samba and then restarting Evolution. Apparently there is a missing dependency in the install.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts. Still an issue in 13.10.